# MSBuild output directory

Tags: build, compilation, msbuild, project

I'm trying to get absolute control over the output of MSBuild. If I run:

```
msbuild project.msbuild
```

or:

```
msbuild project.msbuild /p:configuration=Debug
```

I will get the folder:

- Debug

If I run:

```
msbuild project.msbuild /p:configuration=Release
```

I will get the folder:

- Release

The output directory structure I want is the following:

- Win32\Debug
- Win32\Release
- x64\Debug
- x64\Release

I first tried OutputPath but nothing happened. Then I tried the following:

```
<OutDir>$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
```

Now I get the compiled binaries in the specified folder but for some reason the old directory structure is created to contain the object files. So if I run:

```
msbuild project.msbuild
```

What I end up with is:

- Debug (contains object files)
- Win32\Debug (contains binaries)

I want everything in the same folder, the one I specified, not the default MSBuild decides upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object files are stored in 'Intermediate' directory.
By specifying `OutDir` - you specify location of binaries.
To specify location of .obj files you should additionally try specifying `IntermediateOutputPath` to the desired location of .obj files.

See reference, for example: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2015/04/04/using-a-common-intermediate-and-output-directory-for-your-solution/